aiohttp POST request to GraphQL API returns 'productClientOnlyProduct errors' message
I'm trying to learn some more on aiohttp/asyncio and trying to just print the response using this code below (removed cookies, headers, and query due to length) and I keep getting an error (error below). This seems to work just fine in requests though
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch_data():
    url = 'https://apionline.homedepot.com/federation-gateway/graphql'
    params = {'opname': 'productClientOnlyProduct'}
    cookies = {

    }
    
    headers = {

    }
    
    json_data = {
        'operationName': 'productClientOnlyProduct',
        'variables': {
            'skipSubscribeAndSave': False,
            'skipFavoriteCount': False,
            'skipPaintDetails': True,
            'skipSpecificationGroup': False,
            'skipInstallServices': True,
            'skipKPF': False,
            'itemId': '203077142',
            'storeId': '504',
            'zipCode': '78664',
        },
        'query': ''
    }

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        try:
            async with session.post(url, params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=json_data, timeout=30) as response:
                if response.status != 200:
                    print(f"Error: HTTP status code {response.status}")
                    print(await response.text())
                    return None
                return await response.text()
        except aiohttp.ClientError as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

async def main():
    response_text = await fetch_data()
    if response_text is not None:
        print(response_text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Error:
Error: HTTP status code 206
{
   "data":{
      "productClientOnlyProduct":null
   },
   "error":[{
      "message":"productClientOnlyProduct errors"
   }]
}

Any suggestion(s) would be AMAZING luv u

Check the headers and cookies in your browser for the page. Add those in, subtract to figure out the required ones.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
